# Nodejs: .then() statement does not execute after Promise.all()

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm using nodejs Mongo driver and I want to backup some small collections and insert some data into one collection.

The flow that I came up with is:

- define a function that can backup a collection (by creating a collection with the postfix `_bak`);
- For each collection that I want to backup I call that function and add the call into an array of promise returning functions. `backupProms.push(backupCollection(cb));`
- Then I use `Promise.all(function(parameter)).then(function(){})` to align the promise pipes deterministically and execute a loop of inserts after the collections were backedup and cleared.

However this does not work as expected and I never get to the `.then()` statement that should execute after `Promise.all()`.

**Question**: is this the correct way to handle this situation and what should I do to reach the `.then()` statement that should execute after `Promise.all()`. I think there might be a more elegant approach or solution. Thanks in advance.

```
    var backupCollection = function(collection){
        let backup_coll = collection + "_bak";
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            console.log("About to backup current " + collection + " collection");
            db.createCollection(backup_coll, function(err){
                if(err) throw err;
                // some logic to backup the collections
                });
            });
        });
    }

    for(i = 0, len = backupCollArr.length; i < len; i++){
        var cb = backupCollArr[i];      
        backupProms.push(backupCollection(cb));
    }

    Promise.all(backupProms).then(function(){
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            for (var i = 1; i <= iterations; i++){
                rand1 = polluter_prefix + Date() + Math.random();
                guid1 = genGUID();
                db.collection(insertColl).insert({
                // code to add data
                });
            }
        });
    }).then(function(){
        db.close(function(){
            console.log("Close connection");
        });
    });
```

Comment: There are two `then` functions after `Promise.all`, aren't you getting to any of them? The first seem to return a promise that is never resolved, and so does `backupCollection`?

Comment: you should add an `.catch`. what i see is that `iterations` is undefined.

Comment: It looks like you never call ```resolve``` after the collection is backed up, so you never fulfill the promises, so they Promse.all never gets resolved.

Comment: Where is `resolve` called? You should probably call it in `createCollection` callback after `if(err){}`

Comment: You need to show what is in `// some logic to backup the collections` because you are not showing the `resolve()` call being made in there anywhere. It's commented out, but as everyone is telling you, we actually need to see what is in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are never nor resolving nor rejecting your Promises. 
Here is an example of working solution:

```
var backupCollection = function(collection){
    let backup_coll = collection + "_bak";

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        console.log("About to backup current " + collection + " collection");
        db.createCollection(backup_coll, function(err){
            return err ? reject(err) : resolve();
        });
    });
}

for(i = 0, len = backupCollArr.length; i < len; i++){
    var cb = backupCollArr[i];      
    backupProms.push(backupCollection(cb));
}

Promise.all(backupProms)
.then(function(){
   return;
});
```

`Promise.all`will resolve all the promises in an Array, if Promises are never resolved, it will wait, if all Promises succeeds it will call the `.then`, if one Promise fails it will call the `.catch`.

In your case, it is never resolving because you are never calling `resolve()`, also note that in a Promise chain, meaning in the `.then` or `.catch` you dont have to return a Promise, you can return anything and continue with `.then`, if it throws an error it will be caught in the `.catch`. But if you have an asynchronous call, you must return a Promise. Here is an example:

```
Promise.all([Promise.resolve(true), Promise.resolve(false)])
.then((result) => {
    console.log(result); // [true, false]
    // I want to return the result of an async call with callback
    // I have to return a new Promise
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
         someAsyncCall((err, result) => {
            return err ? reject(err) : resolve(true);
         });
    });
})
.then((result) => {
    console.log(result) // true
    throw new Error('some error');
})
.catch((error) => {
    // my error is caught here
})
```

Comment: Thanks, as others mentioned in the comment, I never added the resolve().